# PCB design - paste coverage calculation for exposed pad (TL;DR version?)

Tags: footprint, qfn, stencil

I have created a Web tool for creating solder mask and paste mask for exposed pad:
  https://jsfiddle.net/d1wang/5t6urzwo/

The idea is get around limitation of DipTrace and help automate footprint design.

Currently, the tool only calculates the total area of the paste stencil apertures. For 3.15x3.15 e-pad with nine ø0.3mm vias, the paste coverage is calculated to be 44%.

I do not think the calculation is accurate (the ratio is way too low). I think we need to take account of the stencil thickness.

Does someone have a "too-long;don't read" equation for the paste coverage and also a standard stencil thickness?

Comment: For components at 0805 and larger, a stencil of 0.006" (150 micron) is pretty standard. For components smaller than that, a 0.005" (125 micron) stencil is common as the thicker paste with small components is prone to tombstoning.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I found a coding mistake in my calculation of e-pad SMD area. The ratio is now 52%.